# 2020 Pro-Tem Moderator Election: Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election

Joomla Stack Exchange had an election last year, and it's time to start thinking about scheduling a new one.

After discussing it with the current moderator team, and to bring the total number of moderators up to 3, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in October 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in October '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: My 2 cents:  Despite launching in 2014, JSE is still relatively immature by several metrics.  New moderators do not necessarily need to commit to daily chores since I check-in multiple times daily.  I believe what JSE needs now are friendly people who are willing to creatively and actively "grow & groom" the community.  Ideally, I would like the mod team to increase in years of Joomla development and activism (CMS contributors, ambassadors, folks with "skin in the game") because depth of Joomla experience is a weak point of mine.

Comment: maybe it's time to just pack this whole JSE thing in, eh JNat? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358032/352329